# How to set Dropwizard's ViewBundle root URL

Tags: java, dropwizard, dropwizard-templates

I tried a lot, but I couldn't find how to choose the root URL for all Dropwizard's ViewBundle resources.

I have my REST endpoints served from `/rest`, because I have set it with `environment.jersey().setUrlPattern('/rest/*'...)`.

I have my static assets served from `/`, because I registered an `AssetBundle`, pointing it to `/` as the root of its URLs: `bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/" + resourceBasePath + "/public/", "/"));`

Right now, if I want to get a view, I have to append `/rest` to its URL. For example, if I set `@Path("/view/person/{id}")`, it will only be accessible at `/rest/view/person/123`.

This is not what I want. I want it to be accessible at `/view/person/123`.

I am guessing technically it must be possible, since `AssetBundle` enables to mount to `/`, there should be a way to mount the `ViewBundle` to `/view`.

How can I do it?

Comment: How did you register your `AssetBundle` exactly?

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt Thanks for the comment. I added the info to the question text